# What is the structure of this JavaScript expression and why does it evaluate to 'true'? (HTML5 audio tag and canPlayType() function)

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I am working through a JavaScript/HTML5 book and have encountered an expression that I don't understand. The code uses JavaScript's .canPlayType() function to check whether a browser supports a given HTML5 audio format (in this case it's checking for mp3 support). The particular expression I'm confused with is on the fourth line:

```
var audio = document.createElement('audio');
var mp3Support;
console.log(audio.canPlayType('audio/mpeg')); // returns probably
mp3Support = "" != audio.canPlayType('audio/mpeg');
console.log(mp3Support); // returns true
```

I'm using Chrome, which supports mp3 files, so the the third line returns 'probably'. However, the fifth line returns 'true'. What is happening in the fourth line that converts the value of 'probably' to 'true'? Is there a name for an expression that follows this structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be confused because you see both the assignment operator `=` and the comparison operator `!=` (not equals). These are not the same. Essentially it is saying:

```
if (audio.canPlayType('audio/mpeg') == "") 
    mp3Support = false;
else 
    mp3Support = true;
```

Which can be reduced to:

```
mp3Support = !(audio.canPlayType('audio/mpeg') == "")
```

And again reduced to what you see:

```
mp3Support = "" != audio.canPlayType('audio/mpeg');
```

Comment: can be further reduced to `!!audio.canPlayType('audio/mpeg') ` :)

Answer (score 3):

`!=` compares expressions using the [abstract equality comparison algorithm](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3), and returns `true` if they are different or `false` if they are equal.

> [**11.9.2 The Does-not-equals Operator ( != )**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.2)
>
> The production EqualityExpression : *EqualityExpression* `!=`
>   *RelationalExpression* is evaluated as follows:
>
> - Let *lref* be the result of evaluating *EqualityExpression*.
> - Let *lval* be [GetValue](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.7.1)(*lref*).
> - Let *rref* be the result of evaluating *RelationalExpression*.
> - Let *rval* be [GetValue](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.7.1)(*rref*).
> - Let *r* be the result of performing abstract equality comparison *rval* == *lval*. ([see 11.9.3](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3)).
> - If *r* is **true**, return **false**. Otherwise, return **true**.

In your case, the empty string `""` is different than the string `"probably"`. So the operator returns `true`.